# Adding hypermedia for resource JSON representation using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am generating my restful resource JSON representation using jackson and it works very well as far as standard property conversion is concerned. However I would also like to generate a bunch of hypermedia in the same json object for which i need to use uriinfo from jersey. Is there a way to pass uriinfo to jackson somehow and use a custom parser to use the uriinfo to generate hypermedia.

jackson version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [jersey-linking](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/pages/DeclarativeHyperlinkingInJersey). It basically uses annotations to generate URIs for you.